# Unwanted Double Quotes in .CSV File

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, reporting-services, export-to-csv

All, tried looking in the wealth of SO for this issue here but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for so here it goes:

I am generating a report with SSRS and saving the resulting file as comma-delimited .CSV file. I need to have every field in the output CSV file to be enclosed in double quotes; however, when I concatenate the quotes in SQL the resulting CSV file has three double quotes around each field vs. expected one double quote on each side.

Is this possible to achieve using only SSRS and what is the most sane method if so?

Comment: What does "concatendate the quotes in SQL" mean? It sounds like there is another step.

Comment: Sorry, the resulting file has no double quotes at all unless I concatenate them in SQL. After I do and preview the report, the render appears correct with a single set of double quotes on the left and right of fields; however, when the render is exported into CSV, I show three double quotes on each side of the field.

Comment: Are you required to display the fields on the SSRS report enclosed in double quotes? Or is the desired result that only the CSV file has a single set of double quotes on the left and right of fields? It seems redundant.

Comment: Tom, the latter - the resulting CSV file needs to have a single set of double quotes on the left and right of fields.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is achievable solely through SSRS and exporting to CSV. The "Qualifier", by design will be included in the field if the delimiter (in this case, a comma), a new line character is present or to escape a single double quote character (which is why they appear as three double quotes). Otherwise, each field is correctly delimited by the comma, and the double quotes aren't necessary to define the field. What are you planning to do with the output?

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Having conversed with colleagues it does appear as if another tool would be required to strip off the extra quotes. The task is export the file as CSV onto a FTP file share to consume by a trading partner,

Answer (score 1):

Since it renders the records containing commas within double quotes, you should change the default Field Delimter to another charatcter (e.g., "|").

See below:

```
<Extension Name="TXT" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
            <OverrideNames>
                <Name Language="en-US">Text File</Name>
            </OverrideNames>
            <Configuration>
                <DeviceInfo>
                    <NoHeader>true</NoHeader>
                    <OutputFormat>TXT</OutputFormat>
                    <Encoding>ASCII</Encoding>
                    <FieldDelimiter>|</FieldDelimiter>
                    <ExcelMode>False</ExcelMode>
                    <Qualifier></Qualifier>
                    <FileExtension>txt</FileExtension>
                </DeviceInfo>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
```